# Is it bad practice to hack the main application_top.php file of osCommerce for making the desired changes?

Tags: php, oscommerce

Is it bad practice to hack the main application_top.php file of osCommerce for making the desired changes?

I am using the osCommerce v2 and I an in the need of making some change in application_top.php file of osCommerce v2.0 its the main file of osCommerce product. 
please guide me is it bad to do this?

My need is I have provided the multiple submission of products at the first page with different details of each, but as I click Add to cart button generally it carries only one product with its id, now in my current situation i am available with multiple product ID, how can i proceed further to shopping cart without hacking the main application_top.php code?

Comment: I'd probably rephrase the question to, "Is it *bad* practice", as it's rarely good practice to hack something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends, if you want to update the platform later, i will answer to you NO PLEASE!!

But if you understand what you're doing and plan to NEVER update the platform, HAVE IT YOUR WAY :)

Comment: thanks for the edit @Palantir, my english is a little poor... :/